How to call async javascript function and get the returned value using robot framework
I have a async javascript function stored in a robot framework variable. I need to call this async function using robot framework and get the returned value. I tried as below and its not working. Can someone please help on this.
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${ASYNC_JAVA_SCRIPT_FUNCTION}    async function calculate(input1, input2) { return input1 + input2; }

*** Test Cases ***
Call And Validate Async JavaScript Function
    Open Browser    about:blank    HeadlessChrome

    ${result}=    Execute Async Javascript    return (${ASYNC_JAVA_SCRIPT_FUNCTION})(3, 5);
    Log    ${result}

    Close Browser


Write the javascript function into a js file into your working directory and try the below robot framework code. Use robotframework-seleniumlibrary  6.5.0
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${ASYNC_JAVA_SCRIPT_FUNCTION}       ${CURDIR}${/}addtwonum.js



*** Test Cases ***

Call And Validate Async JavaScript Function
    Open Browser
     ...     about:blank
     ...     Chrome
     ${getfile}=     Get File        ${ASYNC_JAVA_SCRIPT_FUNCTION}
    ${result}=    Execute Javascript
    ...     ${getfile}
    ...     return calculate(1, 2);


    Log    ${result}

    Close Browser

